# How can I get rid of these unwanted empty spaces in my scraped data?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am scraping numbers of travelers to foreign countries(link included in code below). Because numbers above 999,999 are part of a different class than the lower numbers, I had to use two separate Xpaths to retrieve all of the data. 
I successfully print the data, but for some reason there is an extra space in front of and following all of the numbers from the 'bignum' class. Anybody know how I an get rid of these spaces within my code? Cleaning the csv file up in Excel is an option, but it would take hours of my time.
Keep in mind that Some of the empty spaces in the data are actually supposed to be there, as those countries do not have any recorded data for the corresponding year.

```
# import python packages
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re

r = requests.get('http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/ST.INT.ARVL/countries/1W?page=4&order=wbapi_data_value_2014%20wbapi_data_value%20wbapi_data_value-last&sort=asc&display=default')
data = html.fromstring(r.text)

Data1995 = []
Data_1995 = data.xpath("//tr/td[2][@class='views-field views-field-wbapi-data-value-1995 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first']/text()|//span[@class='bignum']/text()")

for i in Data_1995:
    i = i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
    i = re.sub('[()]', '', i)  # removing ()
    Data1995.append(i)

Data1995
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 separate XPaths and check all of the classes. Keep it simple:

```
Data1995 = [i.text_content().strip() 
            for i in data.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'wbapi-data-value')]")]
```

Comment: That is an alternate XPath, however the unwanted spaces still remain.

Comment: @SamB yeah, you mean the empty items in the list? Sure, these are the countries that don't have the traveler values.

Comment: No, the empty spaces that appear before and after any number that is 1,000,000 or higher. They keep the data from lining up correctly in a spreadsheet.

Comment: @SamB gotcha, let me investigate that

Comment: @SamB hm, don't have those, this is the code I'm executing: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/3d8683e056b88f8dbe191c844093c883.

Comment: Hmm yeah I think it must have to do with me trying to append the data or something